# Getting an Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object(...) is not a function while binding data to dropdown

Tags: binding, dropdown

Here is the code

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Account Information").items.select("ID").get().then((items: any[]) => {
    console.log(items);
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        console.log(items[i].ID);
        var option = jQuery("<option/>");
        option.attr("value", items[i].ID).text(items[i].ID);
        jQuery("#accountIds").append(option);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your question is a little bit bare bones. You might want to add some more info, like a stack trace, or some short info on what you're trying to do. (You didn't even actually ask a question.) Plus, this sounds like the kind of problem that can be solved 3 minutes after opening a debugger, but is relatively hard to solve for someone who is not you and can't run your code.

Comment: I'm trying to bind sharepoint list items ids to Dropdown In Sharepoint framework in page load

Comment: Go the F12 route and check what the variable values are, are those console.log not helping?